# Does NativeScript support certificate pinning|

Tags: ssl, nativescript

I'm doing some research on cross-platform mobile development with NativeScript and I've been unable to find any information on certificate pinning in NativeScript. I know Telerik provides the secure-http module to achieve true certificate pinning for hybrid mobile apps, maybe I looked over it in their roadmap.

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add more information to your post so we can understand what you're trying to do/ asking about?

Comment: The idea is to find out how secure NativeScript is, so we want to know whether https is supported or not. To know if https is supported or not we need to know if true certificate checking can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it via one module is called `nativescript-https`

Install the plugin:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-https
```

You required to setup certificate as well, Please check this [nativescript-https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-https) for more details